# Difference between minimizing a function by gradient descent and by norm minimization?

Tags: optimization, neural-network, l2-norm

I have working on 2 ways of training a neural network.  The first method uses gradient descent updates the model with Adam optimizer. the second method minimizes the norm of the gradient of the functions and updates the network. What is the difference between the two? does normal gradient descent guarantee minimum norm of the cost function? I am using binary cross entropy loss function. How does minimizing the norm of the gradient works?

Comment: The cost function is a scalar, and gradient descent minimizes this scalar function. It doesn't make sense to take the "norm of the cost function".

Comment: While performing gradient descent we can calculate the norm of the jacobian matrix and try to minize it correct? Will that help? I mean Jacobian matrix consisting of all the parameters in the neural network. I think the parameters are in vector space but what is the role of the norm in optimizing a function?